# SQL Update set value where

Tags: sql-server

Could someone tell me why this statement doesn't work?

```
UPDATE [database].[dbo].[dynamic_Inventory]
SET [database].[dbo].[dynamic_Inventory].[property] = 'no' 
WHERE [database].[dbo].[dynamic_Inventory].[AgentId] = [database].[dbo].[Temp_Inventory].[memberUID]
```

I get the error

> The multi-part identifier "database.dbo.Temp_Inventory.memberUID could not be bound. But the column "memberUID" does exist.

This is for SQL Server.

Comment: `SET property = `...

Comment: `WHERE AgentID = ` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are referring to a table -- `Temp_Inventory` that has no reference in the `FROM` clause.

This looks like SQL Server, so I would recommend using an explicit `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE di
    SET property = 'no'
    FROM di JOIN
         [database].[dbo].[Temp_Inventory] ti
         ON di.AgentId = ti.memberUID;
```

Or `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE di
    SET property = 'no'
    FROM di 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM database.dbo.Temp_Inventory ti
                  WHERE di.AgentId = ti.memberUID
                 );
```

Notice how table aliases and removing square braces makes the query much easier to write and to read.